# break list of list and save it to dynamic variable in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create dynamic variables using list of lists.

I am able to generate list of lists dynamically to given dictionary.

```
dictPrintList = {'myDistKey': ["The mask value '1'","The mask value", "The mask value 2","The mask value 3","The mask value 4","The mask value 5"]}
listFromDict = dictPrintList["myDistKey"]    

def divide_in_chunks(l, n): 

    for i in range(0, len(l), n):  
        yield l[i:i + n]

n = 2

dictListInChunks = list(divide_in_chunks(listFromDict, n))
print(dictListInChunks)
```

## here 3 list generated dynamically

## how to break the list here dynamically like list_1 list_2 _list_3

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way -

```
dictPrintList = {'myDistKey': ["The mask value '1'","The mask value", "The mask value 2","The mask value 3","The mask value 4","The mask value 5"]}
listFromDict = dictPrintList["myDistKey"]    

def divide_in_chunks(l, n): 

    for i in range(0, len(l), n):  
        yield l[i:i + n]

n = 2

dictListInChunks = list(divide_in_chunks(listFromDict, n))
counter = 1
for item in dictListInChunks:
    varItem = {}
    var = "%s%s" % ("var_", counter)
    varItem[var] = item 
    counter +=1
    print(varItem)
```

Output is:

```
{'var_1': ["The mask value '1'", 'The mask value']}
{'var_2': ['The mask value 2', 'The mask value 3']}
{'var_3': ['The mask value 4', 'The mask value 5']}
```